# AIR/IOS - Need working example of GameCenter using Adobe Gaming SDK 1.3

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, game-center, leaderboard

Using the FREE Adobe Gaming SDK 1.3 example of the GameCenter does not work/compile. When I try to create an instance of GameCenterController, it says that it is null.

// Class var
private var gcController : GameCenterController;

// In the constructor after GameCenterController.isSupported = true.
gcController = GameCenterController();
trace( gcController ); // Returns null.

I am just trying to NOT spend $70 on some code from MilkManGames (http://www.milkmangames.com/blog/tools/#iosgc) when this should work just fine, provided free from the source.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You're not including the GameCenter ANE properly. You have to add the ANE file as a Native Extension (if you are in Flash Builder, Project>Properties>Flex/ActionScript Build Path>Native Extensions) and you must include it in the project for the proper platforms (in Flash Builder, Project>Properties>Flex/Actionscipt Build Packaging>iOS>Native Extensions).

No example will help you here since you aren't properly including the Native Extension in the first place.